# Trigger INSERTING into a row

Tags: oracle, trigger, plsql

I am trying to create a Trigger that will fire when a new student is being added to the table. It should update the a table called: MAJOR, by incrementing its MCOUNT domain by one.

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT(
SID     CHAR(7),
SName       VARCHAR2(20),
SMajor      CHAR(3)
CHECK (SMajor in ('CSC', 'MIS', 'TDC')),
CONSTRAINT PK_STUDENT
PRIMARY KEY (SID) 
);



CREATE TABLE MAJOR(
MName       CHAR(3) PRIMARY KEY,
MCount      NUMBER(3) ); 
INSERT INTO MAJOR VALUES ('CSC', 0);
INSERT INTO MAJOR VALUES ('MIS', 0);
INSERT INTO MAJOR VALUES ('TDC', 0);
SELECT * FROM MAJOR;
COMMIT;
```

My trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER addingS
AFTER INSERT ON STUDENT
    FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE 
        counter NUMBER (3);
    BEGIN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Adding student.');
        counter := counter + 1;
        UPDATE MAJOR
        SET MCOUNT = counter
        WHERE MCOUNT = 0; 
    END;
    /
```

It is not updating, now my MCOUNT's value is empty, why is that?

Answer (score 0):

I think that `counter` is `NULL` because you don't assign it a value. And after you increment it, nothing changes because `NULL + 1 = NULL`. Also your UPDATE will not work if `MCOUNT` is not 0.

Unrelated: I suggest to use a foreign key instead of `CHECK`.

Answer (score 0):

You define a variable, `counter`. However, you never set it to a value, which means its value is NULL. `1 + NULL` yields NULL.

Note that this won't work as you want, anyway:

- Even if you initialize `counter` to 0, that going to be done *for each row*. So, for every student, you'll have `counter` set to 1, and you'd set `MCOUNT` to 1, not the number of students with the major so far.
- Since you're only setting `MCOUNT` if it is currently zero, even if `counter` was set to the number of students with the major, the `UPDATE` statement would only be run once, and `MCOUNT` would still always be 1.
- Finally, you're not checking the students `SMAJOR`, and only updating the `MAJOR` record for that major. Whatever value `MCOUNT` holds for one major, it will hold for all of them.

A couple of notes:

- You can use the current value of `MCOUNT` to update `MCOUNT`. You do need to either make sure `MCOUNT` is either never NULL, or treat a NULL value in `MCOUNT` as a zero.
- You need to make sure you're only updating `MCOUNT` for the major you're concerned with.

Something like

```
    UPDATE MAJOR
       SET MCOUNT = NVL(MCOUNT, 0) + 1
     WHERE MAJOR = NEW.SMAJOR
```

should work well.

Also, of course, note that you need to handle changing counts if a student changes their major, or if a student is removed from the system.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you could use a trigger that picks up the mcount value from table MAJOR, and increments it (via an UPDATE) whenever a student is added to the STUDENT table.  However, this will raise a NO_DATA_FOUND exception when the MAJOR table is empty.  Thus, we start populating the MAJOR table (with an INSERT) in this situation.

```
-- create the 2 tables, then compile the trigger

create or replace trigger addstudent
  after insert on student
  for each row
declare
  counter number(3) := 0 ;
begin
  select mcount into counter
  from major
  where mname = upper( :new.smajor ) 
  for update ;

  dbms_output.put_line( 'Student added to ' || :new.smajor || ' group.' );
  counter := counter + 1;
  update major
  set mcount = counter
  where mname = :new.smajor ; 
exception
  when no_data_found then
    dbms_output.put_line( 'Table MAJOR: no entry for ' || :new.smajor || '!' ) ;
    insert into major ( mname, mcount ) values ( :new.smajor, 1 ) ;
    dbms_output.put_line( 'Table MAJOR: row for ' || :new.smajor || ' INSERTed.') ;    
end;
/

Trigger ADDSTUDENT compiled
```

**Testing**

```
begin
  insert into student ( sid, sname, smajor ) values ( 'a1', 'Frank', 'CSC' ) ;
  insert into student ( sid, sname, smajor ) values ( 'a2', 'Lorna', 'CSC' ) ;
  insert into student ( sid, sname, smajor ) values ( 'a3', 'Colin', 'CSC' ) ;
  insert into student ( sid, sname, smajor ) values ( 'a4', 'Harriet', 'MIS' ) ;
  insert into student ( sid, sname, smajor ) values ( 'a5', 'Michael', 'MIS' ) ;
  insert into student ( sid, sname, smajor ) values ( 'a6', 'Dorothy', 'MIS' ) ;
  insert into student ( sid, sname, smajor ) values ( 'a7', 'Harriet', 'TDC' ) ;
  insert into student ( sid, sname, smajor ) values ( 'a8', 'Michael', 'TDC' ) ;
  insert into student ( sid, sname, smajor ) values ( 'a9', 'Dorothy', 'TDC' ) ;
end ;
/

-- output
Table MAJOR: no entry for CSC!
Table MAJOR: row for CSC INSERTed.
Student added to CSC group.
Student added to CSC group.
Table MAJOR: no entry for MIS!
Table MAJOR: row for MIS INSERTed.
Student added to MIS group.
Student added to MIS group.
Table MAJOR: no entry for TDC!
Table MAJOR: row for TDC INSERTed.
Student added to TDC group.
Student added to TDC group.

SQL> select * from major;
MNAME  MCOUNT  
CSC    3       
MIS    3       
TDC    3
```

See [dbfiddle here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d3c75e76f947e27b4da0841149fa5958).

Even if this works initially, it may be better to use a VIEW (and ditch the trigger(s)).  Maybe you don't need the MAJOR table at all ...

```
create or replace view major_vw
as
select 
  smajor
, count(smajor) as mcount
from student
group by smajor 
;

-- testing
SQL> select * from major_vw;
SMAJOR  MCOUNT  
MIS     3       
CSC     3       
TDC     3
```

See [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=95d930947c306cb2d3c24d931d9dd907).

Comment: A DML can occur between SELECT..INTO and UPDATE clause.  You should lock that row (eg FOR UPDATE) or do it with a single UPDATE statement.

Comment: @MichaelKutz - Thanks for pointing this out!